# Building Spring example for Flex with Maven

Tags: java, flash, apache-flex, spring, maven

Has anyone got a working example of a Spring supported Flex app which builds using maven?

I checked out the Java/Flex example at:

```
svn co http://svn.springbyexample.org/flex/simple-flex-webapp/tags/1.1/ simple-flex-webapp
```

but got the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project simple-flex-webapp: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.springbyexample.web:simple-flex-webapp:war:1.1: Failure to find com.adobe.flex.framework:flex-framework:pom:3.2.0.3958 in http://www.springbyexample.org/maven/repo was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of springbyexample.org has elapsed or updates are forced
```

I tried tweaking the flex-framework dependency version with no success.

Answer (score 0):

The following Nexus search proves that the dependency exists:

https://repository.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;gav~com.adobe.flex.framework~flex-framework~3.2.0.3958~~

Have you added the Flex releases repository to your POM's releases section?

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>flexmojos</id>
      <url>http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/flexgroup/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

The following tutorial describes how to enable flex in Maven:

http://ria.dzone.com/articles/flex-and-maven

Comment: Thanks, The error now is The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.adobe.flex:compiler:pom:3.2.0.3958, org.graniteds:granite-generator:jar:1.1.0, com.adobe.flex.compiler:asdoc:zip:template:3.2.0.3958: Failure to find com.adobe.flex:compiler:pom:3.2.0.3958 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Comment: If you are using Maven 3 you can force an update by running Maven with the "-U" option. Another option is to delete the local cache ($HOME/.m2/repository) and force everything to be downloaded fresh.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same error? Even after deleting the local repository? Assuming it's a new error, the next thing to check is whether you are running behind a corporate firewall (preventing direct access to the internet).

Answer (score 0):

Decided finally to create a new project with a Flex module with a simple Java data service module. To get started I used

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeRepository=http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/public -DarchetypeGroupId=org.sonatype.flexmojos -DarchetypeArtifactId=flexmojos-archetypes-modular-webapp -DarchetypeVersion=${flexmojos.version}
```

to create the module. Also I had to ensure that FlashPlayer.exe was on the current path for the maven build(!)

It was straightforward then to add on another module Java based with Spring support.